# Javascript - sort alpha then numeric

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array something like:

```
['honda accord', '1986 honda accord', '1990 honda accord', '2000 honda accord', '2011 honda accord', '2016 honda accord'].
```

I need to sort this in javascript so that the result is:

```
['honda accord', '2016 honda accord', '2011 honda accord', '2000 honda accord', '1990 honda accord', '1986 honda accord'].
```

how can i do this.

```
array.sort()
```

does not work.
I know i need to send a function to sort.

Thanks
Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `split` and check first item of the string

```js
var arr = ['honda accord', '1986 honda accord', '1990 honda accord', '2000 honda accord', '2011 honda accord', '2016 honda accord'];

arr.sort((a, b) => b.split(' ')[0] - a.split(' ')[0])

document.write(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Working Fiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/7nu7bp3g/

```
var arr = [
          'honda accord',
          '1986 honda accord',
          '1990 honda accord',
          '2000 honda accord',
          '2011 honda accord',
          '2016 honda accord'
          ];

var sortArr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
return b.split(' ')[0] - a.split(' ')[0];
});

console.log(sortArr);
```

I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very elegant (or efficient) but it works. Essentially it uses Regular Expression to extract the year from each car and then compare.

```
// the regular expression to extract the year and car
var regEx = /((\d+)\s)*(.*)/;

var list = ['honda accord', '1986 honda accord', '1990 honda accord', '2000 honda accord', '2011 honda accord', '2016 honda accord'];

// custom sort function
list.sort(function(a, b)
{
    // get the car details
    var aR = regEx.exec(a);
    var bR = regEx.exec(b);

    var aCar = aR[3];
    var bCar = bR[3];

    var aYear = aR[2];
    var bYear = bR[2];

    // compare the strings
    if(aCar < bCar) return -1;
    else if(aCar > bCar) return 1;
    // we'll only get this far if both strings are the same

    // if there was no year provided then it should be first
    else if(!aYear) return -1;
    else if(!bYear) return 1;

    // at this point the car types are the same, and both have an year so compare the year
    else if(aYear < bYear) return 1;
    else if(aYear > bYear) return -1;
    return 0;
})
```

You could make it more efficient by pre-processing the list to run the regex on all of the items.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with replace if no year is given

```js
var array = ['honda accord', '1986 honda accord', '1990 honda accord', '2000 honda accord', '2011 honda accord', '2016 honda accord'];

array.sort((a, b) => b.replace(/^\D*$/g, '9999 $1').localeCompare(a.replace(/^\D*$/g, '9999 $1')));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```